# AppCenter Crashes and Firebase Crashlytics - Both Together Not Working - Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, crashlytics, visual-studio-app-center

Trying to integrated both Firebase Crashlytics and AppCenter Crashes in single application. I see, none of this is able to log any crashes.

```
   public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    
  {
        

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
        Crashlytics.SharedInstance.Init();
        
        AppCenter.Start("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
      

        LoadApplication(new App());
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Also, I am using latest SDKs.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.8.0.1451" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.5.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics">
      <Version>4.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes">
      <Version>4.1.0</Version>
   </PackageReference>
   <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core">
     <Version>6.10.4</Version>
   </PackageReference>
   <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics">
     <Version>4.6.2</Version>
   </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Also, from the Visual Studio Console Log, i am receiving below error logs.

```
 [Crashlytics] The signal SIGABRT has a non-Crashlytics handler (sigabrt_signal_handler).  This will interfere with reporting. 2021-02-24 12:26:30.173858+0530 DemoApp.iOS[12308:580294] 6.34.0 - 
 [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Warning: NSUncaughtExceptionHandler is '_ZL17exception_handlerP11NSException' in '/Users/sakeridilipkumar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CC5157E9-F6A5-46D8-BA9E-B2D67936538D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/41E5D8C0-19FC-474C-84B9-EDFC5C9B024A/DemoApp.iOS.app/DemoApp.iOS' 
 [Crashlytics] The signal SIGBUS has a non-Crashlytics handler (mono_sigsegv_signal_handler).  This will interfere with reporting. 
 [Crashlytics] The signal SIGFPE has a non-Crashlytics handler (mono_sigfpe_signal_handler).  This will interfere with reporting. 
 [Crashlytics] The signal SIGILL has a non-Crashlytics handler (mono_crashing_signal_handler).  This will interfere with reporting. 
 [Crashlytics] The signal SIGSEGV has a non-Crashlytics handler (mono_sigsegv_signal_handler).  This will interfere with reporting. 
 [Crashlytics] The signal SIGSYS has a non-Crashlytics handler (mono_crashing_signal_handler).  This will interfere with reporting. 
 [Crashlytics] The signal SIGTRAP has a non-Crashlytics handler (MSplcrash_signal_handler).  This will interfere with reporting.
```

Any suggestion to find rootcause is appreciable.

Comment: Did you add `AppCenter.Start("ios={Your App Secret};android={Your App Secret};uwp={Your App Secret};windowsdesktop={Your App Secret}", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));` in your `OnStart()` method of `App.xaml.cs` file.

Comment: As far as I know, in iOS Crashlytics doesn't support multiple crash reporting frameworks because there can be conflicts, your last logs seem like a reference to this.

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved.

I have kept below packages only and it started working. I have also needed to upload dSYM file to upload. Please upload same dSYM which was generated while archived.

```
<ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.8.0.1451" />
 <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.5.3.2" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics">
  <Version>4.1.0</Version>
 </PackageReference>
 <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core">
  <Version>6.10.4</Version>
 </PackageReference>
 <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics">
  <Version>4.6.2</Version>
 </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Wait.Where is `Appcenter.Crashes` nuget in this?